# ios date time in am pm date formatter issue

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsdate, nsdateformatter

i am trying to change date string get from data base to date(mm.dd.yy) and time(am pm).
this way i am getting date time from sqlite:

```
rs=[db executeQuery:@"select *,strftime('%m.%d.%Y %H:%M',update_date) AS DATETIME from sales_order where deleted=0 and status=1 and customer_id=?  order by order_id desc",custId];
```

i get date time string :

```
        NSString *dateTimeString = [rs stringForColumn:@"DATETIME"];//from nslog 02.25.2014 14:41
```

then i initiate date formatter and get date:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[self getCurrentLocale]];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm dd YY hh:mm a"];//it is nil,i am stuck here also tried with mm.dd.YY hh:mm a
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateTimeString];
```

Any suggestion
thanks

Comment: You have multiple "." in your date string showed by NSLog. But they don't appear in your `dateFormat`. Plus there are two "mm", for the month and the minutes, one should be in uppercase. If I remember well (didn't try), you should use something like that: `MM'.'dd'.'YY hh:mm a`.

Comment: Have you solved your question?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use `NSDataDetector`.

---

Whether you're not sure (or don't care) about the date format contained in the string, **use NSDataDetector for parsing date**.

```
NSString *dateString = @"Wed, 03 Jul 2013 02:16:02 -0700";
__block NSDate *detectedDate;

//Detect.
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingAllTypes error:nil];
[detector enumerateMatchesInString:dateString
                           options:kNilOptions
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [dateString length])
                        usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
{ detectedDate = result.date; }];
```

---

Made an **NSString extension** for that.

```
// Simple as this.   
date = dateString.dateValue;
```

Thanks to [NSDataDetector](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it recognizes a whole lot of format.

```
'2014-01-16' dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
'2014.01.16' dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
'2014/01/16' dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
'2014 Jan 16' dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
'2014 Jan 16th' dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
'20140116' dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
'01-16-2014' dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
'01.16.2014' dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
'01/16/2014' dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
'16 January 2014' dateValue is <2014-01-16 11:00:00 +0000>
'01-16-2014 17:05:05' dateValue is <2014-01-16 16:05:05 +0000>
'01-16-2014 T 17:05:05 UTC' dateValue is <2014-01-16 17:05:05 +0000>
'17:05, 1 January 2014 (UTC)' dateValue is <2014-01-01 16:05:00 +0000>
```

Part of [eppz!kit](https://github.com/eppz/eppz-kit), grab the category [NSString+EPPZKit.h](https://github.com/eppz/eppz-kit/blob/master/eppz!kit/NSString%2BEPPZKit.h) from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried following code:-

```
    NSString *dateStr = @"02.25.2014 14:41";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
    NSLog(@"date = %@",date);
```

And I got Following output log:-

```
date = 2014-02-25 09:11:00 +0000
```

Let me know, It will help or not.